# Explaining get() method with **kwargs?

Tags: python, methods, keyword-argument

Trying to figure out how this code is working.

I understand that `**kwargs` returns a dictionary and the `get()` function searches the dict for a given key and returns a default value if not found.
However in the code I don't understand is if the `get()` method is searching for example: "clock" or self.clock or both.

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.screen = kwargs.get("screen",self.screen)
    self.clock = kwargs.get("clock",self.clock)
    self.active = kwargs.get("active",self.active)
```

Here is an example call to this method:

```
debug.update(active = numActive)
```

From my understanding, the variable `numActive` is passed through the update method as active and then as `**kwargs` which is then searched for via the `get()` method. Couldn't I just remove the use of `kwargs` seeing as I know how many parameters are needed?

Any help with understanding is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

The second parameter in the get method is the default value.

According to Python2.7's documentation:

> get(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

**Explanation**
When you try to 'get' something from a dictionary, if the key is not found, or the value is None, it will return None.

BUT, if you provide the second parameter (which is the default), **if and only if** the key is not found, default value will be returned.

*Example without defaults*

For the following code:

```
some_dict = {
    "key_1": 1,
    "key_2": None,
}
print some_dict.get("key_1")
print some_dict.get("key_2")
print some_dict.get("key_3")
```

You will get the output:

```
1
None
None
```

*Example with defaults*

For the following code

```
some_dict = {
    "key_1": 1,
    "key_2": None,
}
print some_dict.get("key_1", 1)
print some_dict.get("key_2", 2)
print some_dict.get("key_3", 3)
```

You will get the output:

```
1
None
3
```

**Looking at your code**

I will explain your code in the comments:

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # If the kwargs contain the key 'screen', the following get method will
    # return its value, or else it would remain whatever value was in 
    # self.screen's variable before
    self.screen = kwargs.get("screen",self.screen)


    # If the kwargs contain the key 'clock', the following get method will
    # return its value, or else it would remain whatever value was in 
    # self.clock's variable before
    self.clock = kwargs.get("clock",self.clock)

    # If the kwargs contain the key 'active', the following get method will
    # return its value, or else it would remain whatever value was in 
    # self.active's variable before
    self.active = kwargs.get("active",self.active)
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

This expression:

```
kwargs.get("screen",self.screen)
```

is equivalent to this expression:

```
kwargs["screen"] if "screen" in kwargs else self.screen
```

This statement:

```
self.screen = kwargs.get("screen",self.screen)
```

is equivalent to these statements:

```
if "screen" in kwargs:
    self.screen = kwargs["screen"]
else:
    self.screen = self.screen
```

Note that it is *not* equivalent to these statements:

```
if "screen" in kwargs:
    self.screen = kwargs["screen"]
```

Because the statement

```
self.screen = self.screen
```

raises an `AttributeError` if `self.screen` is not yet defined. See that error in action by running the following program:

```
d = {}
x = object()
x.attr = d.get("attr", x.attr)
```

You can do away with `kwargs` by implementing `update` instead as:

```
def update(self, screen=None, clock=None, active=None):
    if screen is not None: self.screen = screen
    if clock is not None: self.clock = clock
    if active is not None: self.active = active
```

And then you can call `debug.update` and specify whichever of the keyword arguments you want. Defining it this way has the advantage that it raises a `TypeError` if you try to call it with a keyword argument other than `screen`, `clock`, or `active`.

One caveat is that if you really mean to say `debug.update(screen = None)`, then calling it that way actually does nothing; it does not set `debug.screen` to `None`. One way to get around that is to write this at the top of your file:

```
_UNSPECIFIED = object()
```

And then implement `update` as:

```
def update(self, screen=_UNSPECIFIED, clock=_UNSPECIFIED, active=_UNSPECIFIED):
    if screen is not _UNSPECIFIED: self.screen = screen
    if clock is not _UNSPECIFIED: self.clock = clock
    if active is not _UNSPECIFIED: self.active = active
```

Comment: This is perfect, I think removing kwargs in the way you suggested is the best solution as there is no moment where any of screen, clock, and active are set to None. Thank you for this response!

Answer (score 5):

`kwargs.get()` retrieves a keyword argument passed to a function.

The first argument is the keyword and the second is the default value if there was no argument provided for the keyword.

```py
from uuid import uuid4

def my_function(**kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get("id", uuid4().hex[:6])
    name = kwargs.get("name", None)
    print(f"{id} - {name}")

my_function(name="Alice")
```

> a1b2c3 - Alice

```py
my_function(name="Bob", id="d4e5f6")
```

> d4e5f6 - Bob

```py
my_function()
```

> g7h8i9 - None

Answer (score 1):

```
self.screen = kwargs.get("screen",self.screen)
```

This gets the "screen" value from `kwargs`. If its not there, it just uses whatever happens to be in screen at the moment and stuffs it back into screen. Its the same as

```
if "screen" in kwargs:
    self.screen = kwargs["screen"]
```

In other words, `update` only changes values that are passed as keyword arguments. This seems like a complicated way to do a simple thing. There must be a use case for it, but, generally, yuck.

*Couldn't I just remove the use of kwargs seeing as I know how many parameters are needed?*

In the example, no. It will set zero, onem two or three attributes depending on whether they are in `kwarg`. You could even put other values like `update(foo="bar")` and it would just ignore them.

So, here are two ways to set the attribute:

```
debug.update(active = numActive)
debug.active = numActive
```

I'm leaning towards the second way. Leaning **way** over!

Comment: Hi, I'm having a pretty hard time getting my head around this but using debug.active = numActive seems to make a lot more sense to me. I was thinking is there a way to get rid of the use of kwargs? I don't think the use case is as severe as you may think.

Comment: You'd have to search your code base and fix whoever is using it. I've done something kinda similar (only kinda!) so that objects could pick and choose dynamic configuration parameters at run time. Look how its used and if it doesn't seem reasonable, then I would certainly be temped to change it.

Comment: I appreciate your responses however I think you are overestimating me slightly haha, this is my first time using classes and programming a project in python generally! I would be embarrassed to show you my own code let alone take ideas from yours.